# Cannot extract the user score details for the anime while scraping using requests and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner to web scraping, I was scraping this particular web page https://myanimelist.net/animelist/Arcane where I was unable to fetch the user score details though my python code using requests and Beautiful Soup. Can't find what i am doing wrong. Please help.
My progress so far in the code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def scrape_user_profile(username):
    url = f"https://myanimelist.net/animelist/{username}"
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Find the table containing the anime list
        tbody_list = soup.find_all("tbody", class_="list-item")

        if tbody_list:
            data = []

            for tbody in tbody_list:
                anime_row = tbody.find("tr", class_="list-table-data")
                title_element = anime_row.find("td", class_="data title clearfix").find("a", class_="link sort")
                score_element = anime_row.find("td", class_="data score").find("span", class_="score-label")
                if title_element and score_element:
                    title = title_element.text.strip()
                    score = score_element.text.strip()
                    data.append([username, title, score])

            if data:
                with open('user_score.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file)
                    writer.writerow(["Username", "Anime Title", "Score"])  # Write column names
                    writer.writerows(data)
                print(f"User details saved for username: {username}")
            else:
                print(f"No anime list found for username: {username}")
        else:
            print(f"No anime list found for username: {username}")
    else:
        print(f"Error occurred while fetching user profile for username: {username}")

usernames = ["Arcane"]

for username in usernames:
    scrape_user_profile(username)
```

the data is fetched and written in this format:

Username    Anime Title Score
Xinil   ${ item.title_localized || item.anime_title }   ${ item.score != 0 ? item.score : "-" }

Comment: questions needs information of what you have tried and what the results were

Comment: I am fetching user score details for anime from multiple users by reading their usernames from a CSV file. With the help of 5eb's answer, the issue with the previous code has been resolved.

However, I have encountered another problem. Upon further inspection, I discovered that not all users' web pages have the same HTML formatting. As a result, the resolved code is unable to fetch the details for all users.

To better understand my problem, please refer to my comment below 5eb's answer.

Comment: put that into your question not into a comment please is my point

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the page you're scraping uses some kind of client side rendering.

This basically means that dynamic parts of the web page are rendered by the browser using Javascript. Not all things you see rendered on the page have to actually be inside of the page's html file.

For example:

```
${ item.score != 0 ? item.score : "-" }
```

Luckily the actual values you're looking to scrape do exist inside the html page, just not where you expect them to be. The table on the page has a `data-items` attribute which holds the values we want as a JSON string.

They've probably put the actual data inside the html page for SEO purposes, but that's just my guess.

Here's how you could scrape the data:

```
data_items = soup.find("table", {"data-items" : True}) # Gets the data-items attribute value
data_items_parsed = json.loads(data_items.get("data-items")) # parses Javascript object from JSON string

# Now we just need to loop through the data and send it to your csv file
data = []
for data_item in data_items_parsed:
  data.append([username, data_item['anime_title'], data_item['score']])

if data:
  with open('user_score.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Username", "Anime Title", "Score"])  # Write column names
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The code uses `json` so be sure to import it.

Comment: Hello 5eb,
So now I'm trying to fetch user score list details from MyAnimeList using a CSV file with usernames. However, there are formatting issues on certain anime list pages.
My code works for most users, like [Example URL](https://myanimelist.net/animelist/midnightq2), but not for [Problematic URL](https://myanimelist.net/animelist/Hiromi).
I've tried handling the formatting in this Google Colab notebook:[ Link to Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_d0NeWl5SLyP5Ad5bQdleEqtYblAjgMv#scrollTo=iLbbcHez7Lz3). Any insights or suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: The main problem in your other scripts is the value of `table2` when scraping https://myanimelist.net/animelist/Hiromi. If you inspect its value you see it actually refers to the table on the top of the page that contains  'Currently Watching', 'Completed', etc... So this table doesn't contain the scores or titles. This page is very weird in that there are a lot of tables with only row...

Comment: In this case I would not bother looping through the tables if you only care about the titles and scores. I would do a `find_all` targeting class `score-label` for scores and a `find_all` targeting class `animetitle` and the span inside for the titles. Then you have everything, you'd just need to extract the text content for both.

Comment: Yes, I had already discovered the mistake I was doing in my code and successfully resolved the issue. After making the necessary adjustments, the code is now functioning perfectly.